# Trouble get special character in retrofit 2 and gson

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to get a json list from a web service. 
This is the json string return by server : 
`[{"categoryName":"Política"},{"categoryName":"Economía"},{"categoryName":"Cultura"},{"categoryName":"Deportes"}`
The problem is converting in to the POJO. The special characters (í) it's appear like "**Pol�tica**".
This is the retrofit call function :

```
  @GET("categories")
  public Call<List<CategoryPojo>> getCategorias(@Query("sitename") String site)
```

this is the callback function:

```
    Call<List<CategoryPojo>> call = restservice.getApiService().getCategorias(medio);

    try {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoryPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoryPojo>> call, Response<List<CategoryPojo>> response) {
                List<CategoryPojo> categories = response.body();
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onDataLoaded(categories);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoryPojo>> call, Throwable throwable) {
                   Log.e("Retrofit Error", throwable.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

this is the POJO:

```
public class CategoryPojo implements Serializable{

    public CategoryPojo() { }

    @SerializedName("categoryName")
    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
      return this.name;
    }


 }
```

The result of the request to the Web services, (output in browser) is :

```
[{"categoryName":"Política"},{"categoryName":"Economía"},{"categoryName":"Cultura"},{"categoryName":"Deportes"},{"categoryName":"Salud"},{"categoryName":"Ciencia y Tecnología"},{"categoryName":"Medio Ambiente"},{"categoryName":"Medios"},{"categoryName":"Militar e Inteligencia"},{"categoryName":"Sociedad"}]
```

So, the return json has a good encoding...i think that maybe is about the way retrofit read the response.
I'm using retrofit-2.0.2, gson-2.6.1, converter-gson-2.0.2, okhttp-3.2.0.
Any help? please

Comment: Where exactly is that output? Are you logging the variable itself after the output has been stored in it?

Comment: What’s the `Content-Type` header on the server’s HTTP response? You can see this in your browser’s dev tools.

Comment: @Jesse: Well, the raw response by the debugger (androidStudio) has the Content-type set to application/json.

Comment: @DanielK : the output is the result of make a request to the WS in the Chrome browser (you mean the correct array of categories?) I don't understand the second question...please explain to me.

Comment: @user636189, I was wondering if this `it's appear like "Pol�tica"`, is coming from your logcat. If you try the request in your browser, it comes back as Política right?

Comment: @DanielK, exactly.

Comment: @user6361891, I'm trying to figure out if the request comes in clean from the API, I had issues using interceptors to see the body of the request. I would check stetho by Facebook to see if the request comes in okay and it just deserializes wrong.

Comment: @DanielK. I suppose too it's a trouble of deserializes, but all this job is make by gson and converter-gson libraries.

Comment: @user6361891, can you post the request itself so I can give it a shot?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Content-type` in the response headers. Look for the `charset` value and try to change that on the backend side to `application/josn;charset=UTF-8`. That worked for me.